# Parameter panel hidden for Report linked to an image (SSRS)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I created 2 ssrs reports.
-- naming: (ReportNr1 = R1) and (ReportNr2 = R2)

R1 uses a date range to return data, something like

> WHERE TransDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

R2 has an embedded image which I want to link to R1 when it's clicked.

All works 100% in VS, but as soon as I deploy the report, the parameter panels are missing on R1, when the image is clicked...

When I view R1 directly (not via the link of R2) then the Date Picker is there and it works perfectly

Please help, as I've been researching this error for hours, with zero luck

thanks in advance!!

Fadiel

Comment: What do you mean _the parameter panels are missing on R1_? Is parameter panel hidden or are parameter values empty?

Comment: The report(R1) runs, it returns values, but only shows the default view.                  I have a default StartDate and EndDate. So in other words, the design is such that I'm meant to have a DatePicker to select dynamic Date ranges for R1. In this case the DatePicker is not Coming up/Not showing/Hidden?

Comment: In such case, just remove default value for `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`.

Comment: thanks. I thought of this, but how do I get R1 to land on a view with values/data. The requirement is that the report opens on the "CURRENT MONTH" which is why I'm using a dynamic default

Comment: Removing the default worked, but I don't want the parameter to be visible at the cost of now landing on a blank page, as the client requested that the landing page need to always be the Month-to-Date data

Comment: I can understand why it's not accepting the values from the parameter, but I guess I'mm then looking for a clever "hack" or "work-around"

Comment: Just a suggestion: Could you please merge these comment into question?